# How to customize scrollbar on Windows using WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, scrollbar, custom-controls

Recently, I have seen various applications with customized scrollbar ("skinned" ?) 
A good example for such application is Sublime text editor.

I goggled this subject without any meaningful results, so the question is:
Is it possible to customize a Windows scrollbar using WinAPI (assuming I code in C/C++ **only**), no .NET, C# etc, just plain old C/C++

If it is possible, can someone give a tutorial link or better, a working small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that if you want to use only C/C++ you will need to create your own scrollbar from the beginning. I mean you have to create special child window which would process the incoming messages and sending notifications to parent window.

Comment: I was afraid of this kind of answer ;) any example online that can help me get started?

Comment: Do I know ... Controls are precisely described in MSDN. Also another useful info can be found there.